# Why React conditional import only works on dev environment, but not on production

Tags: reactjs

I create a react app and have this part of code in my project:

```
componentWillMount(){
  if(Constantes.CURSO === 'POS') {
    require('./posgraduacao_exclusivo.scss')
  } 
}
```

When I use "npm start" to run it on my machine, it works well, in this case, the value of "Constantes.CURSO" is "GRADUACAO", the if condition is false and the line "require('./posgraduacao_exclusivo.scss')" is not called.

But when I use npm run build, to create the build production, it won't work well. Even the if condition is false, the line "require('./posgraduacao_exclusivo.scss')" is called.

Why is this happening? How can I fix this problem?

UPDATE:

This is my Constantes.js file

```
//export const AMBIENTE = "DESENVOLVIMENTO"
//export const AMBIENTE = "PRODUCAO"
export const CURSO = "GRADUACAO"
//export const CURSO = "POS"
//export const CORS = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
export const CORS = "http://127.0.0.1:8091/"
//---------------FIXED VALUES-----------------//
export const URL_INIT = "https://pucminas.instructure.com/api/v1"
export const URL_PREFIX = CORS + URL_INIT
export const PER_PAGE_VALUE = 25
```

I need to change the variable "CURSO"(comment and uncomment) because I work with 2 different setups.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you set `Constantes.CURSO` when `process.env.NODE_ENV` switches to `production`?

Comment: Also, `Constantes.CURSO` doesn't sound like a constant, feels like it should be in input into your component, fixing that has a chance of fixing the problem. Constants shouldn't be wrapped in ifs, are you mutating your constant?

Comment: I updated the question with the content of the file Constantes.js

Comment: How do you import `Constantes`?

Comment: import * as Constantes from './components/Controller/Constantes'

Comment: Can you try and change to declaring const's and then exporting like so export { A, B, C }

Comment: Btw I would prefer to write a `config-1.json` and `config-2.json` with an object with the props holding my preferred values. Then import the one you want to use during your build with `import config from "./config-1.json"` or swap 1 with 2

Comment: @Julian I just give up, I try to do everything that you said. But it didn't work. Instead of trying to use the "if" to call the require(importing the CSS file), I modified my code to pass CSS classes that I use via props and it works that way.